# DialogFragment changes size suddenly

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have a class which extends DialogFragment. When I click on a button, the dialog shows. The first time is normal, I mean the size is the one of the layout of the dialog. However, when I dismiss the dialog and I click on the button for the second, third,... time, the dialog covers all the screen and I don't know why at all. All methods are always called, so why this happens?

Here is the implementation of the DialogFragment:

```
public class DialogFragmentAzione extends DialogFragment
{
private View view;
private SetVocabulary setVocabulary;
private LinkedList<String> linkedListGruppi;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if(getArguments().getSerializable(Constants.codiceArgomentoDialogFragment) instanceof Set)
        setVocabulary = (SetVocabulary) getArguments().getSerializable(Constants.codiceArgomentoDialogFragment);
    else
        linkedListGruppi = (LinkedList<String>) getArguments().getSerializable(Constants.codiceArgomentoDialogFragment);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutdialogfragment, container);
    view.findViewById(R.id.aggiungiDialog).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextAggiungi);
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            if(text.contains(" ")||text.contains(".")||text.contains(",")||text.contains(";")||text.contains("-")||text.contains("_")
                    ||text.contains(":")||text.contains("@")||text.contains("ç")||text.contains("°")||text.contains("#")||text.contains("§")
                    ||text.contains("{")||text.contains("}")||text.contains("[")||text.contains("]")||text.contains("(")||text.contains(")")
                    ||text.contains("(")||text.contains("!")||text.contains("%")||text.contains("£")||text.contains("&")||text.contains("/")
                    ||text.contains("=")||text.contains("?")||text.contains("'")||text.contains("^")||text.contains("<")||text.contains(">")
                    ||text.contains("<")||text.contains("|")||text.contains("€")||text.contains("+")||text.contains("*"))
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Il testo contiene caratteri non ammessi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if(text.length()<3)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Il testo è troppo corto",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if(text.length()>15)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Il testo è troppo lungo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            {
                if(setVocabulary!=null)
                    setVocabulary.add(text);
                else
                    linkedListGruppi.add(text);
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
{
    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme);
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
}
}
```

Here is the creation of the dialog:

```
dialogFragment = new DialogFragmentAzione();
bundleFragment = new Bundle();
bundleFragment.putSerializable(Constants.codiceArgomentoDialogFragment,setVocabulary);
dialogFragment.setArguments(bundleFragment);

getActivity().findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "Dialog");
        }
    });
```

**The first 4 lines are exectued only one time**

Comment: put false on view declaration.. `    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutdialogfragment, container, false);
`it will stop attaching the dialog fragment to root layout..

Comment: @AalapPatel it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line of code:

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme);
```

In this way the dialog will be always of the same size.